# implement pagination in GXT tree view

Tags: tree, pagination, treeview, gxt, treegrid

My application has a GXT tree view(search) which populates over 600 objects that sometimes leads to a java script error (script not responding) thrown in IE. How do I resolve this issue? I was thinking about some kind of pagination to limit the data to 100 rows at a time. But is it possible to implement pagination along with tree view or a tree grid? I couldn't find any examples anywhere for tree view + pagination? Anyone knows how to address this situation?

Comment: According to me there may be a issue with the request time out. I faced this kind of same issue with grid and solved from server side.

Comment: i figured a way to filter data to 100 rows at a time (kind of pagination), by default it shows tabs like (records 1-100, records 101-200) and then once I click those individual tabs, it loads the details.